# How can i put two divs and one nav into the header at the top-left, top-center and top- right with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put into the `<header>` three divs: div1(logo) at the top left of the page, nav2(menu bar) at the top center of the page and div3(social networks) at the top right of the page, but i dont know how to do that. i tried this code (html):

```
<header>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="links">
        <a></a>
    </div>
</header>
```

and the css:

```
nav{
    background-color: #215177;
    border: 1px solid #215177;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#logo{
    height: 120px;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}

nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#links{
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: Is that all of your HTML? The `a`, `li`, `ul`, `nav` and first `div` are not closed. The browser will try to determine the right positions itself, but it will probably put everything inside the first div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely lacking a lot of code, and depending on whether this will be used in Mobile, will be another issue.

Here is a good starting point, make sure you start and end all DIVS and content in your layout, otherwise, you will not get a finished product properly displayed.

[Here is a working example, of close to what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/mikon1982/zt2q5d0r/), using same classes and ID's:

```
<header> 
<div id='logo'>Logo</div> 
<nav> 
    <ul> 
        <li> 
            <a href='#0'>Home</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href='#0'>About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='#0'>Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='#0'>Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>    
<div id='links'>Links go here</div>
<div class='clear'></div>              
</header>
```

I have also added some basic CSS to the example as well for a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div id="top">
    <header> 
        <div id="logo"></div> 
        <nav> 
            <ul> 
                <li> 
                    <a></a> 
                </li> 
            </ul> 
        </nav> 
        <div id="links">
            <a></a>
        </div> 
    </header>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#top{
    width:100%;
}
#logo{
    width:9%;
    float:left;
}
nav{
    width:78%;
    float:left;
}
#links{
    width:9%;
    float:right;
}
```

**Note**
if you see the total width of nav + link + logo isn't 100% in case you have applied padding in your css.